# WMIC cannot install file with wildcard in file name

Tags: wix, jenkins, windows-installer

I am trying to use Jenkins to install a versioned msi on a target machine like this:

```
wmic /node:"[HOST]" /user:"[USER]" /password:"[PASS]" product call install true ,"", "\\[HOST]\D$\WebsitesDirectory\Product.*.msi"
```

The file name will contain the version number so I can't hard-code this into the wmic command.  But wmic doesn't seem to be able to install a file using a wildcard and quietly fails to install when I run this command. It appears that it has to have the exact path and filename of the file to install it. Does anyone know a way of using wildcards within file names or perhaps a better workaround?

Another possibility is this - Is it possible to get the exact name of the file that Jenkins pulled in via the copy artifact plugin?

Comment: So what would be your expected behavior if there was more then one MSI there?

Comment: I am copying from a job that can only produce a single msi so I am assuming that the wildcard would only ever expand to a single file.

Comment: Bad things have a tendency of happening when you make assumptions.

Comment: Yes, and this is why I added the last paragraph to my question. Unless this is possible I can't see any way to ensure that only one gets installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently this is not a wmic issue but a windows cmd one. I found that this solves the problem:

```
for %%f in (*.msi) do (
  wmic /node:"[host]" /user:"[user]" /password:"[pass]" product call install true, "", "\\[host]\D$\WebsitesDirectory\%%f"
)
```